# Nested resources linking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, nested-resources

I have a category with a subcategory and the subcategory has posts. I'd like to link it as following:

`/categoryname/subcategoryname/post_id/postname`

I've tried doing so by putting this in my routes:

```
  resources :categories do
    resources :subcategories do
      resources :posts
    end
  end
```

But any time I'd like to create a link for my subcategories (`/categoryname/subcategory/`) via `link_to(subcat.name, category_subcategory_path)`

I get:

`No route matches {:controller=>"subcategories", :action=>"show"} missing required keys: [:category_id, :id]`

How would I approach this to get the desired link setup?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Slugs**

Firstly, if you're looking to use [slugged routes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL), you'll be best looking at gems including [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) or [slugalicious](https://github.com/RISCfuture/slugalicious) -- basically allows you to manage "slugs" for your models -- saving titles or other attributes in URL encoded format

---

**Paths**

Secondly, I think you'll resolve your issue by providing values, rather than using the path helper. I would do this:

```
link_to subcat.name, category_subcategory_path(category.id , subcat.id)
```

When you use a `path helper`, it only cares about which `params` you send. The path helper you're using requires you to set the `category_id` and `subcategory_id` params -- which you should pass to the path helper as demonstrated above

This will create the path using `id`'s - if you'd like to use `slugs`, you'll need to use one of the aforementioned gems ([friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) is recommended) to set up the slugs in your app